# SOQL results returning RecordTypeId which is not included in query

Tags: soql

I am running this script from developer console.

```
List<Account> lstAccount = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingStreet From Account LIMIT 1];
System.debug(lstAccount);
```

**Debug Log:**

> 23:47:04:012 USER_DEBUG [5]|DEBUG|(Account:{Id=0019000001nNLGEAA4, Name=Acct_nm001, BillingStreet=xyz Road, RecordTypeId=01290000000iaNiAAI})

I never queried for `RecordtypeId` in SOQL, but it is included in the list.

Although, if I run the query from the query editor, it is not showing `RecordtypeId` column.

Is this by design? Then why not Salesforce is not providing us audit fields in the first scenario.

Comment: I don't see the same behaviour in my spring 17 Developer edition org with the same code running in developer console.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this. @javanoob have you defined record types for Accounts in your org?

Comment: @martin you are correct. I tried in a different org and I see this. In my developer edition org record type is not enabled. Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Apex Code, the SOQL engine automatically includes RecordTypeId and Id in any query result, even if you don't ask for it. There are a few other hidden parameters that appear in a query when presented to the SOQL engine.

For example, if you don't include a LIMIT statement, or set it to higher than `1+Limits.getLimitQueryRows()-Limits.getQueryRows()`, the system automatically adds or changes the limit to `LIMIT :1+Limits.getLimitQueryRows()-Limits.getQueryRows()`. This is how the governor limits are enforced. The exception to this is for Batchable classes that use a Database.getQueryLocator statement, where the limit is set 50,000,001 rows. Also, when you don't specify ALL ROWS, Apex Code silently includes a filter `IsDeleted = FALSE`. In other words, whatever you put into your code isn't necessarily what will be executed by the SOQL engine.

Note that this means the following two queries are (approximately) the same in Apex Code:

```
Account[] accounts1 = [SELECT Id, RecordTypeId, Name, (SELECT Id, RecordType, Name FROM Contacts WHERE IsDeleted = FALSE) FROM Account WHERE IsDeleted = FALSE LIMIT :1+Limits.getLimitQueryRows()-Limits.getQueryRows()];
Account[] accounts2 = [SELECT Name, (SELECT Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account];
```

I don't know if there's a documented reason why RecordTypeId was specifically included, while audit fields were not, but I seem to recall that this behavior did not always exist in Apex Code, which suggests to me that some new SObject method was added that required this field to be present to function correctly. My best guess is that this field was needed for the Visualforce runtime engine to correctly render dynamic picklists on records.

Comment: That behaviour can’t be taken for granted. Always query all you want explicitly

Comment: @stwissel It's better to, but knowing the corner that salesforce.com has painted themselves in to, I suppose they'll never get rid of at least Id as an automatic suggested field. I do agree that you should explicitly list all the fields you need, though, because it makes the code easier to read and gives you better compilation errors. Id is the only field I routinely leave out of my queries.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to point CurrencyISOCode which would also included by default, if your Org is Multicurrency enabled one.