# Does SOQL return Id, RecordType fields always, without requesting?

Tags: apex, soql, fields, id

I have seen Salesforce returning Id field, and RecordType field in SOQL.
for example,

```
Account acc = [select Name from Account limit 1];
System.debug('Returned Id: '+acc.Id);
```

Are these fields always returned by SOQL? Or at certain times (tried this in EXEC Anonymous). Any other fields returned without being requested? Wondering if there is any documentation reference available for this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Apex yes, these fields are always queried. Not all SOQL though. For example the Query Editor or REST API will only return explicitly requested fields.

Comment: Additionally in Tests the `RecordTypeId` [won't be queried](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/195122/2513).