# Comparing two instances of the same custom sObject

Tags: apex, custom-object, sobject

I have two instances of one custom object and want to compare all of their fields to make sure they are exactly the same. I have the code below:

```
CustomObject__c validCustomObject = new CustomObject__c(...);
CustomObject__c queriedCustomObject = [SELECT ... FROM CustomObject__c WHERE Name validCustomObject.Name];
System.assertEquals(validCustomObject, queriedCustomObject);
```

But the assertion fails. I have confirmed that the two variables have exactly the same fields and ids and want to find a way to compare them. I can build an equals() method but is there such a method for sObjects so I don't need to implement it myself?

Comment: A difference in a single field - an Id in one instance and no Id in the other instance or a single field queried in one instance but not set in the other - makes the objects not equal. I've tried to rely on the built in equals logic, but have always ended up writing my own method so I can restrict the logic to the fields that matter for the business logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equals does work (e.g. `validCustomObject == queriedCustomObject`), but remember that [queries include hidden fields](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155979), so you'd have to also include those fields in those constructed objects. It's usually easier to just construct a record from the query, then use `equals()` or `==` on the constructed object:

```
CustomObject__c queriedObject = [...];
CustomObject__c compareObject = new CustomObject__c(Field1=queriedObject.Field1...);
System.assertEquals(validCustomObject, compareObject);
```

This is marginally faster than writing your own equals method.