# Can I use System.assertEquals in this way?

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

This is a generic question I had while I am learning Unit tests on the Salesforce.

Are these **System.assertEquals** statements are valid while implementing Unit test?

```
    System.assertEquals(testConsList[0].Cases, ctrl.consList[0].Cases);
    System.assertEquals(testConsList[0].Opportunities, ctrl.consList[0].Opportunities);
```

**Note:** I didn't get any error while saving the test class. Also I didn't see any issues while running the test class by **Run Test**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as long as the same fields and records are queried in the same order, the assertion should be fine. Just be aware that assertEquals is incredibly sensitive to any minor change (even so much as a change in capitalization of a single character). It's rare to use assertEquals for this purpose, but as long as you're careful about it, it'll work fine. Make sure you use `ORDER BY`, and also make sure that you query the exact same fields in both queries. Avoid using a constructed list (e.g. `Account[] records = new Account[0]; records.add(new Account(...));`), because the query engine may [add extra fields you don't expect](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/155980) and cause the assertion to fail.

Comment: So, I can use **Plural** sObjects, i.e, Cases, Opportunities, OpportunityContactRoles, AccountContactRelations and so on, while asserting? Correct?

Comment: @AustinEvans Yes. There must be the same number of elements in each list, they must contain the same type of SObject in each index, and each record in the same index must contain the same fields and the same values for each field.