# Querying loopup field in SOQL and getting (null fieldName) but the field is coming in direct query

Tags: soql, lookup

I have 2 objects Case (Case) and LiveMessage Session (LiveText__Conversation_Header__c)

when I am querying

```
SELECT Id,  Case.LiveMessage_Session__r.LiveText__EndedTime__c  FROM Case
```

I am getting the following output -
[image]

When I am doing direct query I am getting following output

Query

```
SELECT Id, LiveText__EndedTime__c FROM LiveText__Conversation_Header__c
```

OUTPUT - 
[image]

Note: I have created a look up field in Case which is pointing to Live message field, With that also I'm getting the same issue.

Lookup screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: I think what you are seeing is just the result of the Developer Console's inability to correctly parse the query results. If you execute this query in anonymous Apex you will see the results are there. Try `System.debug([SELECT Id,  Case.LiveMessage_Session__r.LiveText__EndedTime__c  FROM Case]);`

Comment: Hi, Nice idea but it is showing the id alone. second field it self is not coming.

Comment: It also looks like you are confusing LiveMessage Session and LiveMessage Header objects.

Comment: Live Message Session is the label name and LiveText__Conversation_Header is the object name... No confusions

Answer (score 2):

Try following relationship query.

> Case is parent and LiveText__Conversation_Headers__c is child

Here I'am querying from case level,

```
SELECT Id,(select id,LiveText__EndedTime__c FROM LiveText__Conversation_Headers__r) from case
```

**or**

> LiveText__Conversation_Headers__c is parent and case is child

Try below query in Query Editor

```
SELECT Id,LiveText__Conversation_Header__r.LiveText__EndedTime__c FROM Case where LiveText__Conversation_Header__r.LiveText__EndedTime__c!=null
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the quick reply.  with 1st query I'm getting 3000 rows but all are blank and 2nd query is throwing error.

Comment: with respect to above comment pplease find the error here: Didn't understand relationship 'LiveText__Conversation_Header__r' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: Please go to case object and fields ----> copy the lookup name for LiveText__Conversation_Header [Exact name]  and then add __r then write "lookupname_r.LiveText__EndedTime__c "

Comment: Please check soqlquery basics: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_database/units/apex_database_soql

Comment: Hi! I followed the steps but still I'm getting the values like (null LiveMessage_Session__r) for the query "SELECT Id, LiveMessage_Session__r.LiveText__EndedTime__c FROM Case

"

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Id,LiveText__Conversation_Header__r.LiveText__EndedTime__c FROM Case
```

As you have mentioned pls use the **LiveText__Conversation_Header__c** is the child use the relationship query appending __r at last from case. you can get **__r.name** or any other field from the child object.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. In both the ways I'm getting this error "Didn't understand relationship 'Case__r' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names"

Comment: can you please go to case and show me the lookup name of the parent api.add screnot in the question

Comment: Hi I've added the screenshot please check in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer that the value can be null, so if you execute this SOQL it will return blank rows.

When you execute that SOQL in Developer console in execute Anonymous mode then SOQL engine automatically includes Id in any query result.

for more details visit: [SOQL results returning RecordTypeId which is not included in query](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155979/soql-results-returning-recordtypeid-which-is-not-included-in-query)