# parsing json response in soql query to access the data of other object - getting null

Tags: soql, query, json

I’m getting the values from the LiveMessage Session object (When it is an individual query) but when I’m querying it from the Case Object it is showing blank rows (& vice versa).

Comment: and welcome to SFSE! As written, we don't have enough information to help you. Please read more about [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/225300/edit) your question to include additional details. Details like any error messages, framework error messages, etc would be useful, as well as the code you've written so far. The query you are using and any snapshot related to this.

Comment: Well Amit I did that previously but nobody was able to answer. So I thought of not wasting my time here. you can check the question here : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/223691/querying-loopup-field-in-soql-and-getting-null-fieldname-but-the-field-is-comi

Comment: Hope you can answer the question posted on the link. Amit

Comment: Ok. So let's starts with the Start. The parent object **LiveMessage Session** and Case is Child Object?

Comment: No, Case is parent Object and LiveMessage session is child

Comment: What is the Relationship field of the Lookup Filed on **LiveMessage session** Object? Go to LiveMessage session Object open the relationship field and See what is the relationship field?

Comment: This is what I'm getting when doing a query "SELECT CaseNumber,LiveMessage_Session__c FROM Case || Output>> "|DEBUG|Test 1{5003C000001Jww4QAC=Case:{CaseNumber=00001014, Id=5003C000001Jww4QAC}

Comment: I changed the lookup field name to "LiveMessage_Session_lookup"

Comment: From Your Query, It seems that Case is Child Record. It which Object do you have Lookup Field Case OR LiveMessage Session

Comment: Case is having it Live message session also has one

Comment: Hi Amit i hope you are still trying to help

Comment: Please let me know If you need additional information.

Comment: Amit are you still there ... :P