# Soql giving id for field when qurieng lookup field

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

For below query:

```
System.debug([SELECT Id, Account_lookup__r.Account_Number__c FROM Case]);
```

I'm getting:

> 12:05:52:125 USER_DEBUG [1]|DEBUG|(Case:{Id=5003C000001YKoSQAW}, Case:{Id=5003C000001YKoNQAW}, Case:{Id=5003C000001YKoIQAW}, Case:{Id=5003C000001YKoDQAW}, Case:{Id=5003C000001YKo8QAG}, Case:{Id=5003C000001YKo3QAG}, Case:{Id=5003C000001YKnyQAG}, Case:{Id=5003C000001YKntQAG}, Case:{Id=5003C000001YHQLQA4}, Case:{Id=5003C000001YH0RQAW}, ...)

Now how to access that.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! As written, we don't have enough information to help you. Please read more about [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/227281/edit) your question to include additional details. Details like any error messages, framework error messages, etc would be useful, as well as the code you've written so far.

Comment: Hi Amit, you post this comment on all my questions please use the screenshot provided to you in previous question it is the same. Thanks

Comment: Hi Amit please use this link to see the details: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/223691/querying-loopup-field-in-soql-and-getting-null-fieldname-but-the-field-is-comi

Answer (score 1):

The `Account_Number__c` field that you want to access is on the record related through the `Account_lookup__r` relation, assuming it is the standard Account object, you would want to do:

```
list<Case> Cases = [SELECT Id, Account_lookup__r.Account_Number__c FROM Case];
for ( Case c : Cases ){
    System.debug( c );
    Account a = c.Account_lookup__r;
    System.debug( a );
}
```

---

If you want to assign to a variable the value of the `Name` field of the record being referenced by the lookup, you would need to declare a String type variable (since the `Name` field is a text string), and then use the assignment operator (`=`) to give it a value.

```
list<Case> Cases = [SELECT Id, Account_lookup__r.Name FROM Case];
for ( Case c : Cases ){
    System.debug( c );
    Account a = c.Account_lookup__r;
    if ( a != NULL ){
        String AccountName = a.Name;
        System.debug( AccountName );
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly need to use getsobject here but maybe not

Comment: Thanks! martin I can access the value now, Although It is giving null value.

Comment: Alright @Eric let me try with the getsobject.

Comment: @Mobidoubts since the case records in your question don't have the `Account_lookup__c` field populated, I would expect them to produce `null` in the debug statement here.

Comment: I voted up for this answer. \m/

Comment: @Eric That might have been the safer recommendation since I wasn't sure that this lookup field was referencing the standard account object. If you know the type that you are referencing though, you can access and assign it directly.

Comment: @martin can you pick any random field (for example Name) and show that how it can be assign directly.