# Getting some kind of ID when querieng the field in soql

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

For below query:

```
System.debug([SELECT  ContactMobile FROM Case]);
```

I'm getting:

> 15:13:52:137 USER_DEBUG [1]|DEBUG|(Case:{Id=5003C000001YKoSQAW}, Case:{Id=5003C000001YKoNQAW}, Case:{Id=5003C000001YKoIQAW}, Case:{Id=5003C000001YKoDQAW}, Case:{Id=5003C000001YKo8QAG}, Case:{Id=5003C000001YKo3QAG}, Case:{Id=5003C000001YKnyQAG}, Case:{Id=5003C000001YKntQAG}, Case:{Id=5003C000001YHQLQA4}, Case:{Id=5003C000001YH0RQAW}, ...)

Now how to access that. In soql query editor the same query is giving blank rows.

Comment: It's a List of records. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly.

`ContactMobile` value can be null, so if you execute this SOQL it will return blank rows.

When you execute that SOQL in Developer console in execute Anonymous mode then SOQL engine automatically includes Id in any query result.

Refer my question [SOQL results returning RecordTypeId which is not included in query](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155979/soql-results-returning-recordtypeid-which-is-not-included-in-query)